# Unable to check memory allocation size with sizeof()

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, malloc

I am trying to check the size of pointer memory allocated through `malloc()`. For this I write a program in which I initially allocate memory size of 10. Then insert a for loop and keep increasing memory by using `realloc()`. I am checking memory size by using `sizeof`.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *ptr;
    long int size;
    int count;

    ptr = (char *) malloc(10);
    size = sizeof(*ptr);
    printf("size of ptr is= %d\n",size);

    for(count=11;count<=100;count++)
    {
        ptr=(char *) realloc(ptr,count);
        size = sizeof(*ptr);
        printf("size of ptr is= %d\n",size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting always '1' as output:

[image]

So, please tell me if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: This is a good indication that `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does and that it's a good time to go find a reference on it.

Comment: I don't understand, you allocate 10 items and want to know how many items you allocated?  Why not save the quantity in a variable?

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language. They are two different languages. Since you've only used C constructs in your code, I've taken the liberty of editing your question accordingly. In the future, please constrain your question to either one or the other.

Answer (score 8):

`ptr` is of type `char *`, so `sizeof(*ptr)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char)`, that's why you always get `1` in the output.

In general, there's no portable way to get the memory size from the pointer that `malloc` returns, you need to remember the size manually.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer by my own. Here is the solution (step1) include header file `"#include <malloc.h>"` (step2) and use this line `"size = _msize( ptr );"` to get size

Comment: `_msize` is a Microsoft Visual C extension, and is not defined by ANSI C, POSIX, or any other spec adhered to by other compilers.  *Don't use it*. It is *trivial* to remember the size of your allocation.